# Any way to make button-icon icons in a lightning-data table smaller?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, lightning-datatable, lightning-buttonicon

I've tried e.g.:

```
        {
            type: 'button-icon',
            typeAttributes: {
                iconName: 'utility:jump_to_bottom',
                variant: 'brand',
                iconClass: 'slds-icon_x-small',
                class: 'slds-icon_x-small',
            },
        }
```

but looking at the HTML generated, the styling should probably be on the `button` element but there is no way to set a class there or otherwise influence its styling AFAIK.

Is there a way to make these (blue in the example below) buttons smaller?

[image: icons]